# magento getchildhtml('methods') not working

Tags: magento, methods, payment, checkout

I'm trying to write my own magento template and have a problem with magento onepage checkout:

When i call `echo $this->getChildHtml('methods')` in payment.phtml it returns null.

In my checkout.xml I define my payment block like this:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment" template="checkout/onepage/payment.phtml">
    <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
</block>
```

Normally the methods.phtml should be loaded, or shouldn't? It doesn't load anything. For testing i put static code in methods.phtml. 
I'm no expert in magento, so please someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to this post

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22207/17221

you need to change

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
```

to

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml">
```